# Make it easer to [suggest] deleting tags that are wrong

Tags: feature-request, tags

There is this tag [felix](/questions/tagged/felix) on Stack Overflow. It is apparently not a real/good/proper tag but just flattering someone named Felix. But on the tag wiki edit, there is no button to delete it or propose a deletion.

Shouldn't we add something like this functionality, so that a peer reviewer with reputation 20,000+ can maybe delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the tag isn't used by any questions, it's automatically cleaned up by the system after a certain period of time. I believe it's a month.

---

A month, a day... same thing really. :)

Comment: Ok, this functionality seems like the best

Comment: A tag not used by any questions is deleted after 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

[apache felix](https://felix.apache.org/site/index.html) is an OSGI Implementation!

It is not flattering a guy named felix :D

Comment: If this is the real answer, the tag needs to be named [tag:apache-felix], and possibly a synonym created.

Comment: Maybe it's true that there is something like Apache Felix (the website is a good proof). But I think the tag itself is not made for this purpose.

Comment: @yunzen now that no questions are tagged with it, we'll never know :D